# Comparing 2 sample proportions from independent populations

Tags: proportion, z-test

Consider a hypothetical situation,

[image]

due to a new teaching method being implemented, I want to test whether there is a significant difference in the proportion of students that have passed a particular exam between two batches.

I could use the 2 proportion z test.

Are there any other tests I could use to compare two different proportions from independent samples (even if they don't apply particular case study)?

Comment: which othet tests impeach your mind ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar i came accross a few other tests but not sure if they are applicable -------  http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Non-Inferiority_Tests_for_Two_Proportions.pdf . The other tests seem to to be estimating the proportion parameter using MLE which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you only have the data shown here or do you have also more fine grained data like the marks or similar?

Comment: @Mayou36 nope just this data

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-test for a testt of difference between two proportions  representing two independent samples. The sample sizes of independent samples are large enough to meet the assumption of normal distribution.

Comment: for comparison of two means, we use CLT to show that as n increases irrespective of the prior distibution the mean tends to normal distribution and hence to form the statistic we convert it to standard normal.

Comment: For comparison of proportions what is our assumption that the proportion follows normal as n increases ?

Comment: would you prefer to give a formula or definition of standard normal?

Comment: i dont know if that will help. conceputally im a little confused